# Magento: find product by url_key and then match it to attributes

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

My application needs to be able to add a specific product by url and options to a customers cart programatically. The area I am asking for here is to see if there is a quicker (and easier) method of finding a matching product in the database that needs to be filtered by attributes.

For example: I have url_key "mens-shirt" and I want it in "White", "Medium". So far I have been looping through the products looking for options that are similar to the given filters, and using the product that best matches. But is there a better way of doing this.

A brief example:

```
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->
            getCollection()->
            addAttributeToFilter('url_key', $filters['url_key']);

// psuedo code:
        // Check if product has options
        // Loop each option and check the matching label to the desired filters
        // if matching, then use product
        // continue with program
```

I think it's a bit wasteful to loop everything if I can use some filters to do the job more efficiently.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about `Custom Options` then you can run a custom query,

1. If you want to check single option label then use following query:

   $q = "select * from `catalog_product_option` as cpo
   left join `catalog_product_option_type_value` as tv on tv.option_id= cpo.option_id
   left join `catalog_product_option_title` as ot on ot.option_id = cpo.option_id
   left join `catalog_product_option_type_title` as tt on tt.option_type_id = tv.option_type_id
   where cpo.product_id=".$product->getId()." and tt.title='White' and and tt.store_id=0 and ot.title='Your option title'";

2 . Or if you want to check multiple options then:

$q="select tt.title from `catalog_product_option` as cpo
left join `catalog_product_option_type_value` as tv on tv.option_id= cpo.option_id
left join `catalog_product_option_title` as ot on ot.option_id = cpo.option_id
left join `catalog_product_option_type_title` as tt on tt.option_type_id = tv.option_type_id
where cpo.product_id=1  and tt.store_id=0" and ot.title='Your option title';

You will get an array of option titles. you can simply use `in_array` function to check if your desired option exists or not. like

```
if(in_array('White') || in_array('Black')){
   do something.
}
```

Update the `where` condition accordingly and modify these queries according to Magento way. I was in a hurry :)